# Linq with Left Join on SubQuery containing Count

Tags: .net, linq, count, subquery, left-join

I'm having difficulty translating sql to linq syntax.

I have 2 tables (Category and CategoryListing) which reference each other with CategoryID. I need to get a list of all the CategoryID in Category Table and the Count of CategoryID for all corresponding matches in the CategoryListing table. If a CategoryID is not present in CategoryListing, then the CategoryID should still be returned - but with a frequency of 0.

The following sql query demonstrates expected results:

```
SELECT c.CategoryID, COALESCE(cl.frequency, 0) as frequency
FROM Category c
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT cl.CategoryID, COUNT(cl.CategoryID) as frequency 
    FROM CategoryListing cl
    GROUP BY cl.CategoryID
) as cl
ON c.CategoryID = cl.CategoryID
WHERE c.GuideID = 1
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Not tested, but this should do the trick:

```
var q = from c in ctx.Category
        join clg in 
            (
                from cl in ctx.CategoryListing
                group cl by cl.CategoryID into g
                select new { CategoryID = g.Key, Frequency = g.Count()}
            ) on c.CategoryID equals clg.CategoryID into cclg
        from v in cclg.DefaultIfEmpty()
        where c.GuideID==1
        select new { c.CategoryID, Frequency = v.Frequency ?? 0 };
```

Comment: Frans,
Thanks for the quick reply. This works great except I need a left join on clg.

Comment: Oh! my bad, will fix it. just a sec

Comment: Fixed it. It needed an into clause and a defaultifempty (which result in a groupjoin + defaultifempty call, two of my favorite things to hate about linq as they make writing a linq provider a true hell ;))

Comment: @Neil Barnwell:  You can do left joins in linq by using join and on equals.  For inner joins, instead of using the join keyword, you should use the relational ability of the objects.

Comment: @achinda99: Can you provide an example using the relational ability of the objects?

Comment: @JWalker: I think achinda99 means that if you do:
from c in ctx.Customer
from o in c.Orders
it will become a leftjoin if order.CustomerId is nullable. Though in your case that doesn't apply.

Comment: @Frans: Thank you for update. It worked like a charm with one modification - in the 1st select new, Frequency = (int?)g.Count().

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and moved the entire query to a Stored Procedure on the database. This solves the problem by avoiding LINQ in the first place.

Comment: For complicated queries, it doesn't always make sense to spend time and energy converting to Linq when the SQL is already available.  Consider using a TABLE VALUE FUNCTION as well, as TVF can be schema bound so it has better performance.